# IntentService not starting via Intent Filter in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, intentfilter, intentservice

*FYI This works in Native Android but i'm now porting it to Xamarin*

I have created an IntentService that I wish to start from another application. So I need to be able to start the service via the Intent Filter method rather than by specifying the class directly.

E.g like so from an Activity:

```
Android.Content.Intent intent = new Android.Content.Intent("com.my.command");
StartService(intent);
```

My intent service class is properly decorated like so:

```
namespace Services{
[Service (Exported = true, Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.my.command" })]
 class DataIntentService : IntentService
 {

        protected void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            // this never fires!
        }   


 }
```

}

If I extend Service rather than IntentService it works fine, but I want to use IntentService!

Any ideas why this not working? By the way, I haven't even attempted to send this Intent from an external application yet, this is from within the same application.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to override it: `protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)`?

Comment: Fair point, its just a typo in my code! I do have the override keyword and it does not work